# Relative References to another workbook not working

Tags: excel, indexing, lookup, lookup-tables, self-reference

I would like to use the index-match technique across two worksheets on separate workbooks. The index table is on the *Page Order* worksheet of **Page Order for Merged Surveys.xlsx**. The fill-in table is on the *Page IDs* worksheet of **Page Flows.xlsx.** Both workbooks are open simultaneously, so I'm not worried about file paths. Additionally, both worksheets share the field names, "Page Order" and "Title". Both worksheets have additional fields as well.  Please see the attached images for the set-up of the [Page Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zCEC.jpg) and [Page ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USpCo.jpg) worksheets.

I am attempting to fill in the 
"Page Order" field on the *Page IDs* worksheet by matching the 
"Title" fields.

```
=INDEX('[Page Order for Merged Surveys.xlsx]Page Order'!$A$2:$B$76, 
MATCH(D2,'[Page Order for Merged Surveys.xlsx]Page Order'!$B$2:$B$76,0),1)
```

As you can see, the lookup value "D2" uses a relative reference. Yet, when I fill down the *Page IDs* worksheet, the formula behaves as though D2 is an absolute reference. However, as soon as I hit the save button, the formula realizes that D2 is indeed a relative reference.

But I don't want to have to resave the file constantly just to get the formula to work correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would add the before and after save images, but I don't have enough reputation points to do so.

Comment: Your calculations are set to manual.  Hit F9 or change the calculations to automatic.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem!